# Using 2 different scheduling policies in the same project

Tags: linux-kernel, posix, scheduling, posix-api

In an embedded project,we are facing difficulties in deciding which scheduling policy to use.For certain testcases to pass, we need to use `SCHED_OTHER` and for some other test cases we need to use `SCHED_RR`.But if we set `SCHED_RR`for some task and rest as `SCHED_OTHER`,all the test cases are passing.Was it legal and are there any additional side effects for such usage of two policies in the same project?

Comment: For more clearence of my query, I have service task, Interpreter task,etc. They will do the job of getting the input from the user through FrontPanel and make necessary execution of the steps provided. If i set a policy SCHED_OTHER the auto run cases like getting all the input from front panel automatically and performing their tasks continuously for more than 5 hrs is failing. But if I set that policy as SCHED_RR then it is passing. Since Round Robin gives some importance to high priority task, this may run. But for this policy in somecases the input i provided manually is not accepted. Help

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about Linux?  Then yes, it is perfectly acceptable to have some tasks running with SCHED_RR and others running with SCHED_OTHER.

Note that SCHED_RR tasks will always get to run ahead of SCHED_OTHER tasks.  So it is not surprising that your tests runs better if you set your tasks to SCHED_RR.  The thing to watch out for is that your SCHED_RR tasks might use 100% of the CPU, and starve the SCHED_OTHER tasks.  Maybe this is happening when you say some input is getting dropped.

Michael